# Display image downloaded in tableCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a tableCell in which i need to download image and assign it to the imageView.
I see that the image is downloaded but not sure how I can update my tableCell to reload for me to display that image.
Below is my code and assigning the image in completion handler to imageView. Since it is in completion handler and by the time image gets downloaded tableCell is already displayed. Please advie how can i show image as soon as it gets downloaded

```
public func configureCell(_ employee: Employee) {
 nameLabel.text = employee.name
 addressLabel.text = employee.address

 guard let url = employee.imageURL else { return }

 fetchImageTask = ImageHandler.getImage(forURL: url) { [weak self] image in
  self?.employeeImageView.image = image
 }
}
```

This is my configure method which gets called from cellForRow(at: Index) for my tableView

Please advice

Comment: Are you not getting the image inside the completion handler? Does the fetchImageTask fire automatically?

Comment: Don't load data in the **view** (the cell). Cells are reused and can be deallocated immediately. Load data in the **controller** or the **model**.

Answer (score 0):

Here we need to see an ImageHandler implementation. Maybe you need to run a task first.

```
fetchImageTask = ImageHandler.getImage(forURL: url) { [weak self] image in
   self?.employeeImageView.image = image
}

fetchImageTask.resume()
```

My answer will work if fetchImageTask it is just a task and it needs to be run. (Maybe ImageHandler.getImage has inner run)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire)?

```
AF.request(url).response{
            res in
            if let data = res.data{
                self?.employeeImageView.image = UIImage(data: data)
            }
        }
```